# In winforms, whats the quickest way to make a window that displays the console output?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have some screens making some data queries that might take a long time. My db layer already puts the query strings to the console (I can see them in the output window when debugging). I just want to have a window the user can open to see the same thing if they grow impatient.

Any suggestions on a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you redirect the [`Console.Out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.out.aspx) to an instance of a [`StringWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx), you can then get the text that has been written to the console:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
Console.SetOut(writer);
StringBuilder consoleOut = writer.GetStringBuilder();
string text = consoleOut.ToString();
```

If you do this within a new `Form`, you can then poll at an interval to get the text that has been written to the console so far and put its value into a `TextBox`. A crude example:

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    Console.SetOut(writer);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Tick += (o, s) => textBox.Text = writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    timer.Interval = 500;
    timer.Start();
}
```

---

A few things to be careful with:

- `StringWriter` is disposable, so technically you need to dispose of it when done (although in reality its `Dispose()` method does nothing so not really a big issue).
- `StringWriter` keeps an internal `StringBuilder` containing all of the text written to it so far. This will only ever get bigger over time, so the longer your application runs, the more memory it will consume. You could put some checks in to clear it out periodically when it reaches a certain size.
- If you make the interval too small, you will be constantly using CPU.
- Make sure to set `Console.Out` back to its original value when you close your form, otherwise you will not be able to print messages to the console again.

Comment: I haven't fixed the stringbuilder memory problem yet, but basically, it works. Thanks a bunch. I should be ok from here.

Answer (score 0):

[DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647)

> DebugView is an application that lets you monitor debug output on your local system, or any computer on the network that you can reach via TCP/IP. It is capable of displaying both kernel-mode and Win32 debug output, so you don't need a debugger to catch the debug output your applications or device drivers generate, nor do you need to modify your applications or drivers to use non-standard debug output APIs.

Comment: DbgView doesn't capture Console output, only Debug and Trace. It also won't allow him to show the console output within his own application.

Comment: The OP didn't say how output is generated and I thought he didn't mind an external tool. However, I agree that DbgView won't show Console output just Debug and Trace.